# How to make datetime.now return date in UK format with c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want datetime.now to return the datetime object in UK format. It does so on my local computer but when I upload the code to the server it does it in US format

Comment: You should show the context (code) where `DateTime.Now` occurs. There is probably an implicit `.ToString(null, null)` or `.ToString()`.

Comment: Just set the current culture  of your thread to uk, and all conversions will be ok.

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` doesn't have any format associated with it. Formatting is just for presentation. You can do:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

Or supply a specific/custom format like:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want datetime.now to return the datetime object in UK format.

There's no such concept, any more than an `int` is a value "in hex" or "in decimal". A `DateTime` is just a `DateTime` - you can specify the format when you convert it to a `string`. It's really important to understand the difference between an inherent value, and what it looks like after it's converted to text - very few types are aware of a custom, modifiable format to use when converting themselves - it's either provided externally (as for `DateTime`, numbers etc) or simply fixed.

Before you convert start hard-coding a UK format though, I would strongly advise you to consider *exactly* what you're doing:

- Ideally, avoid the conversion in the first place. A lot of the time, string conversions are unnecessary and can be problematic.
- Is the text going to be consumed by another machine? Use an ISO-8601 standard format.
- Is the text going to be consumed by a person? Use *their* culture rather than some arbitrary one you decide on.

  - ... Or display it in a dedicated control...

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I have a DateTime field in the database. And when I am creating a record from my home computer it stores it in the DB in the UK format, and when you retrieve it, it gives you 04/03/2015 - today's date in UK format. But when you upload the same code to the server it stores the date in the SQL DB and then when you retrieve it it shows as 03/04/2015 - US format. Oh and how I store it is by passing DateTime.Now to SQL parameter

Comment: your date is not stored in the db in UK format at all. You are missing the difference between presentation and how it is phyically stored. If you want to show a date in UK format, that is presentation. The way the date is stored in the db is not changed because of that.

Comment: @user3733737: If you're storing it as text in the database, you should stop doing that. If it's genuinely a DateTime field, then as Philip says it isn't stored in any particular format - just like `DateTime` doesn't have a format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of the ToString method: ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), or: ToString("yy/MMM/dd"), etc. etc.

Read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also sounds to me that you might want to configure your (UI-)Culture in the web.config? Then it will always be in the same format regardless of the culture of your US/Japanese/european server culture..

More about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
LogDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
```

Comment: This won't work the whole year as UK uses Greenwich Mean Time or Western European Time (UTC) and British Summer Time or Western European Summer Time (UTC+01:00)